# Como faço para saber e contar a quantidade de linhas em uma consulta SQL com Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

```
 $teste = DB::table("cnaes")
                ->select("id")
                ->where("cnpj", $cnpj)
                ->where("cnae", $cnae);
```

Como posso saber quantas linhas foram afetadas por esta consulta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `count()`

```
 $teste = DB::table("cnaes")
                ->select("id")
                ->where("cnpj", $cnpj)
                ->where("cnae", $cnae)
                ->count();
```

Comment: Isso resolve,Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

beleza ?

Achei um pouco parecido com o codeigniter essa estrutura aí...

No caso, a sql usada é num_rows... Olha na documentação do Laravel para ver como ela se aplica.

Se for igual ao codeigniter, ficaria assim:

```
   $teste = DB::table("cnaes")
                    ->select("id")
                    ->where("cnpj", $cnpj)
                    ->where("cnae", $cnae);


     echo $teste->num_rows();
```

Comment: Então,usando PDO eu so usava o **rowCount()** e ja resolvia o meu problema,mas agora que tenho que passar para o Laravel estou com dificuldade.

Comment: Use apenas o ->count(); após o ->where("cnae", $cnae); e retira o echo.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta correta é de duas formas

1:

```
$teste = DB::table("cnaes")
                ->select("id")
                ->where("cnpj", $cnpj)
                ->where("cnae", $cnae)->get()->count();
```

2:

```
 $teste = DB::table("cnaes")
                ->select(\DB::raw("COUNT(id)" as quantidade))
                ->where("cnpj", $cnpj)
                ->where("cnae", $cnae)->get();
```

Da uma olhada na documentação que pode haver o `->sum()` não me lembro se houver são 4 formas.

Comment: Ola,apenas o Count() resolve o meu problema,muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Sugiro que escolha uma resposta qual solucionou sua dúvida assim, possa ajudar outras pessoas.